# Mobile Device emulator cannot access localhost

Tags: windows, iis, mobile, emulation

I am using Windows Mobile 6 Professional Emulator and Windows Mobile Device Center. I connected and cradled the emulator to my computer.

I am trying to connect from the browser of the emulator to a webservice that is deployed in the IIS of my computer (same machine where the emulator is installed). If I connect my computer to the internet, I can access any website, including my local WS (using the IP returned by ipConfig). The problem is when I disconnect the computer from the Internet: I cannot access my local web service using the IP (internal one returned by ipconfig), or machine name.

Do you have any ideea what settings am I missing? I am sure this it's possible somehow, I just don't know how...

PS: The goal is to access the WS from a mobile application, but until I cannot access it from the browser, I cannot access it from the application either.

Thank you!

Comment: I seem to have a similar error here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802505/mobile-device-emulator-cannot-access-localhost .  We have workaround about creating a fake connection, and adding a loopback adapter.  Sure would like to know the real problem, real solution though - it doesn't happen on all machines.

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem before, the connection will success if there is network(intranet,internet) on the computer.
If no network connection found it will not work, even if it's a device.

I think it's related to the way that the Emulator/device connect to the computer, finally I solved the problem partially by connecting the computer to a network, if there is no network at all beside the computer you can install **Virtual Machine** to have one :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Wael. Unfortunattly, I could not make it work that way. I already have a Virtual Machine installed on my computer. I started the virtual machine, I am connected now with it, I can access my web service through the browser from the virtual machine using the IP, but still cannot access it from the emulator...

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped to see the URL that you are using. Depending on whether you use the host name, fully qualified domain name, or the IP address, I would suggest different things. Do you have a DNS server in the local network that resolves the host when you are connected? My guess is that with the host's IP address it would have worked. Alas, you asked the question a long time ago and probably no longer need an answer.